# graphql JS returns null when i send a query via graphiql

Tags: javascript, express, schema, express-graphql

I think I have thoroughly checked this code but can't find the error please help!!
I get a null return when I query id

also, vscode tells me my parent in the resolve function is not used. What am I doing wrong here??

express ---

```
const express = require('express');
const graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql');
const schema = require('./schema/schema')

const app = express();

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({

  schema,
  graphiql:true

}));


app.listen(1991, ()=> {
   console.log('1991 live');
});
```

schema --

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const _= require('lodash');

const { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString, GraphQLID, GraphQLInt, 
GraphQLSchema } = graphql;

var drugs = [

{name: 'Paracetamol', price: 200, qty: 20, drugid: 1},
{name: 'Amoxicilin', price: 700, qty: 10, drugid: 2}

];

var categories = [

{name: 'Painkiller', id: 1},
{name: 'Anti-Biotic', id: 2}

];


const DrugType = new GraphQLObjectType({

name: 'Drug',
fields: () => ({
    name: {type: GraphQLString},
    price: {type: GraphQLInt},
    qty: {type: GraphQLInt},
    drugid: {type: GraphQLID}
  })

});

const DrugCategory = new GraphQLObjectType({

name: 'Category',
fields: () => ({
    name: {type: GraphQLString},
    id: {type: GraphQLID}
  })

});

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({

name: 'RootQueryType',
fields: {
    drug:{
        type: DrugType,
        args:{id:{type: GraphQLID}},
        resolve(parent, args){
           return _.find(drugs, {drugid:args.id});

        }
    },

    category:{
        type: DrugCategory,
        args:{id: {type: GraphQLID}},
        resolve(parent,args){
            return _.find(categories, {id:args.id});
          }
      }
  }

});

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: RootQuery
});
```

this is the result i get when i query in graphiql

query --

```
 {
 drug(id: 1){
   name
 }
```

}

result --

```
{
 "data": {
   "drug": null
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a GraphQL query return null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56319137/why-does-a-graphql-query-return-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object you're passing in to lodash's `find` method is `{ id: args.id }` -- that means you're looking for an object with an `id` property that matches `args.id`. However, none of the objects in your `drugs` array have an `id` property. Either update your array or change your search criteria (i.e. `{ drugid: args.id }`).

Additionally, your type for the `id` argument is `GraphQLID`, which is treated like a String. That means `find` is comparing a String argument to a Number property value. Either change the argument's type to `GraphQLInt`, **or** wrap `args.id` with `Number.parseInt`, **or** change the `drugId` values to strings.

Comment: i have updated the lodash method but i'm still getting null after the query, before i added `drugid` it was just `{id:args.id}` and still wasnt working. you think there's something else i'm missing ??

Comment: What's your new method call look like?

Comment: ive updated the code in the question but now looks like this .. `return _.find(drugs, {drugid:args.id});`

Comment: Oops. Just noticed the type for your argument is `GraphQLID`. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: after changing to string i'm not getting a `TypeError: Failed to fetch` error when i query .. omg i'm getting a real headache from this..

Comment: IT WORKED!!!!!! .. thanks alot man ..i hadn't restarted the server that's why i got the failed to fetch error

Comment: can you show me sample code of how i can wrap it with `Number.parseInt` ..i'm already grateful for your contribution.

Comment: This is what I did to get your code working: `return _.find(drugs, {drugid: Number.parseInt(args.id)})`

Comment: THANK YOU!! you have cured my headache simultaneously.